# what is shared variable in java

Tags: java, variables, shared

is there any concept of shared variable in java and if it is what is it?

Comment: Please explain what you are talking about

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean as you can "share variables" or rather "share data" in various ways. I take it that you're a beginner, so I'll make it brief. The *short answer* is **yes**, you can share variables and below are a couple of ways to do it.

**Share data as arguments for parameters in functions**

```
void funcB(int x) {
    System.out.println(x); 
    // funcB prints out whatever it gets in its x parameter
}

void funcA() {
    int myX = 123;
    // declare myX and assign it with 123
    funcB(myX);
    // funcA calls funcB and gives it myX 
    // as an argument to funcB's x parameter
}

public static void main(String... args) {
    funcA();
}

// Program will output: "123"
```

**Share data as attributes in a class**

You can define a class with attributes, when you instantiate the class to an object (i.e. you "*new*" it) you can set the object's attributes and pass it around. Simple example is to have a parameter class:

```
class Point {
    public int x; // this is integer attribute x
    public int y; // this is integer attribute y
}
```

You can use it in the following way:

```
private Point createPoint() {
    Point p = new Point();
    p.x = 1;
    p.y = 2;
    return p;
}

public static void main(String... args)  {
    Point myP = createPoint();
    System.out.println(myP.x + ", " + myP.y);
}

// Program will output: "1, 2"
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `static` keyword, example:

```
private static int count = 1;
public int getCount() {
    return count ++;
}
```

Everytime you call method `getCount()`, `count` value will increase by 1

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share variables between 2 functions, you can use global variables or pass them with pointers.

Example with pointers:

```
public void start() {
    ArrayList a = new ArrayList();
    func(a);
}

private void func(ArrayList a)
{
    a.add(new Object());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what this question means. All public classes are shared, all variables can be shared if they accessible through public methods, etc.

Comment: they can be shared as protected and private too as long as the calling method has access to them.

Answer (score 0):

In the [VB sense](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa711968(VS.71).aspx), a [static field](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) in Java is shared by all instances of the class.

In the [classical sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_Shared_Variables), Java has various RPC, service and database access mechanisms.